# How to fix line break when concatenating string with variable in python?

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to generate a SQL statement with python. Please check the script below:

```
import re

json_file_object = open("sample_json_paths.txt", "r")
sql = list()

for sample_text in json_file_object:

# sample_text = "$.testABM.test.test.test.test.test.testReference"

    sql.append("SELECT\n")
    sql.append("            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', concat(rt.id,'_', @now)), 2) AS docid\n")


    #Append parentnodeid row
    remove_dollar_sign = sample_text.replace("$.","")
    json_string_list = remove_dollar_sign.split(".")
    nodeid = json_string_list.pop(-1)
    parent_node_id = ".".join(json_string_list)
    sql.append("            ,'" + parent_node_id + "' " + "AS parentnodeid\n")

    #Append nodeid row
    sql.append("            ,'" + nodeid + "' " + "AS nodeid\n")

    sql.append("            ,testABM_layer.RequestHeader AS RequestHeader\n")
    sql.append("            ,final_layer.[key] AS final_layer_key\n")
    sql.append("            ,final_layer.[value] AS Ofinal_layer_value\n")
    sql.append("FROM        dbo.test_dataset_backup rt")
    sql.append("""
                OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( rt.test) AS layer_root
                OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( layer_root.value ) 
                    WITH    (
                                    [RequestHeader] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS json,
                                    [test] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS json
                            ) AS testABM_layer\n""")

    #append OUTER APPLY with json sub path
    remove_leading_json = sample_text.replace(".testABM.test","")
    json_string_list = remove_leading_json.split(".")
    json_string_list.pop(-1)
    json_sub_path = ".".join(json_string_list)
    sql.append("            OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( testABM_layer.test, " + "'" + json_sub_path + "'" + ") AS final_layer\n")
    sql.append("            WHERE final_layer.[key] = '" + nodeid + "'\n")

    sql.append("UNION ALL\n")

# print(json_sub_path)

sql_output = "".join(sql)
f = open("sql_statements.txt", "a")
f.write(sql_output)
f.close()

print(sql_output)
```

The line break occurs at Delete due to sensitive informations and Delete due to sensitive informations - before the `UNION ALL`
The issue does not occur at the last loop.
You can also check the sample text from the input file as below:

```
SELECT
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', concat(rt.id,'_', @now)), 2) AS docid
            ,'testABM.test.test.test' AS parentnodeid
            ,'testReference
' AS nodeid
            ,testABM_layer.RequestHeader AS RequestHeader
            ,final_layer.[key] AS final_layer_key
            ,final_layer.[value] AS Ofinal_layer_value
FROM        dbo.test_dataset_backup rt
                OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( rt.test) AS layer_root
                OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( layer_root.value ) 
                    WITH    (
                                    [RequestHeader] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS json,
                                    [test] NVARCHAR(MAX) AS json
                            ) AS testABM_layer
            OUTER APPLY OPENJSON ( testABM_layer.test, '$.test.test') AS final_layer
            WHERE final_layer.[key] = 'testReference
'
UNION ALL
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Thanks

Comment: for whichever database(s) you're working with there should already be a tested library which would handle parameter substitution in an anti-SQL-injection way. is there a particular reason you're doing this without utilizing the DB-API way? it may seem that i'm asking a tangential question, but if you use one of those libraries there's a chance you wouldn't have this issue you're seeing.

Comment: @mechanical_meat, I am using Synapse DW in Azure. The purpose is to Insert the data from json nodes into Synapse tables. So this is the current solution which I can think of for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When iterating over the file contents `sample_text` contains newline characters at the end,
e.g. `'$.SyncCustomerRequestABM.SyncCustomerRequest.Customers.Customer.OriginalSystemReference\n'`

The issue is that the `nodeid` by splitting the line and taking the last element of the split.

You can fix the problem by stripping the `sample_text` at the beginning of each iteration:

```
sample_text = sample_text.strip()
```

The reason why it worked for the last line is that it does not contain the newline character in your file.

---

This will help you with your existing code but I also strongly suggest looking into better ways of generating these string:

- database libraries allow you pass parameters to SQL queries e.g. psycopg https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries
- using f-strings to avoid boilerplate code https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/